# problem with parent() (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, parent-child, parent

problem with parent()

jQuery Code
http://webdev.faressoft.org/wp-content/plugins/ImageSlideShow/js/slideShow.js

You can see the result here (Image Slide Show)
http://webdev.faressoft.org/?p=208

```
$(".ImageNum span").click(function() {
var image = parseInt($(this).text());
$(".correntImage", $(this).parent()).removeClass("correntImage");
$(this).addClass("correntImage");
$(this).parent().parent().children("img").css("display","none");
$(this).parent().parent().children("img").slice(image-1,image).css("display","block");
$(this).parent().parent().children(".autoSlideShow").text("false");
});
```

**why nothing change when i click on $(".ImageNum span") ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem could be the use of `children()` more than the use of `parent()`.

`$(this).parent().parent()` has not direct `<img>` children... has it ?

Try replacing `children()` by `find()` ;)